# Is it possible to do a linearization without introducing new variables?

Tags: linearization, logical-constraints

I have three binary variables $x_{i,j}^{m,r}$ , $y_i^{m,r}$, and $z_i^{m,r}$. There is another integer variable $w_i^r$. And I want to linearize the following logic:

$$ \sum_{m} x_{i,j}^{m,r} \ge 1 \implies w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r}  
 \qquad \forall r, i, j $$

I think to linearize the above I need to introduce another binary. But could we do it without any new variables?

Comment: One small point, I don't believe this family of constraints should be quantified over all $m$. As currently written $m$ is sort of "doubly defined." (This was edited by @RobPratt.)

As for your main question, it would be helpful to know more about your variables. For example, what is the range of $\sum_m y_i^{m,r}$? It would also be helpful to know why you want to avoid introducing variables, and what your overall goal is. Is this a program for a real-world application you are solving with a commercial solver?

Comment: thanks for the heads up @NaturalLogZ yes $m$ was a mistake. but the summation for $y$ and $z$ is over $j$ not $i$, and their bound would be 0 to 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to enforce
$$\bigvee_m x_{i,j}^{m,r} \implies w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r} \quad \text{for all $r,i,j$}$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form leads to linear big-M constraints:
\begin{align}
\left(\lnot \bigvee_m x_{i,j}^{m,r}\right) \lor \left(w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r}\right) &&\text{for all $r,i,j$} \\
\left(\bigwedge_m \lnot x_{i,j}^{m,r}\right) \lor \left(w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r}\right) &&\text{for all $r,i,j$} \\
\bigwedge_{m'} \left(\lnot x_{i,j}^{m',r} \lor w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r}\right) &&\text{for all $r,i,j$} \\
\bigwedge_{m'} \left(x_{i,j}^{m',r} \implies w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r}\right) &&\text{for all $r,i,j$} \\
x_{i,j}^{m',r} \implies w_j^r = w_i^r + \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} - \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r} &&\text{for all $m',r,i,j$} \\
-M(1-x_{i,j}^{m',r}) \le w_j^r - w_i^r - \sum_{m} y_j^{m,r} + \sum_{m} z_j^{m,r} \le M(1-x_{i,j}^{m',r}) &&\text{for all $m',r,i,j$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobPratt it was a new thing to learn for me!  Could $m$ be equal to $m'$?? 
I only need to change index of y and z in summatins to j instead of i . Because that's the one I need in equality too.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted, and please edit your question to make any such corrections.

Comment: can you help me further @RobPratt. I kind of don't get the $m'$ in entirety. why in third line we need to have$m'$ and not use $m$ instead? Any resoan for that?

Comment: The $\bigwedge_m$ and $\sum_m$ have different scope, so when they first appeared together, I renamed the first $m$ to $m'$ to avoid collision.